# HDF format on Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a Modis image with hdf format.

```
fileinfo = hdfinfo('MOD09GA.A2011288.hdf');
```

I'm trying to create a matrix but I only need three bands that are stored on the attributes (I know it because I've checked on Erdas). I've checked the structure of the attributes and there are 12 bands (fileinfo.Attributes= <1x12 struct>). How can I extract and create a matrix with three bands?

```
sds_info = fileinfo.SDS(2);
```

What I'm trying to do is the following...

```
data1 = hdfread(sds_info.Attributes)
```

But I get the following error:

> ??? Error using ==>
>       hdfread>dataSetInfo at 418
>       HINFO must be a structure
>       describing a specific data set
>       in the file.

Checking the help I know I  have to use that structure. How can I know the content of the attributes? How can I select and create a matrix with that information?

```
data1 = hdfread(s.Vdata(1), 'Fields', {'Idx', 'Temp', 'Dewpt'})
```

PS) I'm using the hdftool importing every band. There another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

At the end, this is what I've done (I don't erase the post just in case could help someone):

```
sur_refl_b01_1 = hdfread('MOD09GA.A2011288.h17v05.005.2011293000105.hdf', '/MODIS_Grid_500m_2D/Data Fields/sur_refl_b01_1', 'Index', {[1  1],[1  1],[2400  2400]});
```